# How to display all the results in one line in SWI PROLOG?

Tags: prolog

I have a small databse in the *.pl file which contains various instances of 3 facts:

```
male(NAME)
female(NAME)
parents(CHILD_NAME, MOTHER_NAME, FATHER_NAME)
```

and one question:

```
brother(A, B) :- male(A), parents(A ,X, Y), parents(B, X, Y), X\==Y.
```

which tells when X is a brohter of Y. The question is: is here any way to display all the answers in one line while running the question without hitting ';' for every new instance?

Answer (score 0):

I think I would write once an utility like

```
writeall(Q) :- forall(Q,writeln(Q)).
```

In SWI-prolog there is an handy place where to store utility snippets like this one. From the IDE, click the menu

```
Edit\Prolog preferences
```

and save the snippet there. It get stored in ~/.swiplrc on Linux, MacOS, or into an equivalent configuration file under Windows.